# How to use the current price of the candle and not the close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to know if the current price of a candle can be used, not when it closes, which is using the close, but at the exact moment. I asked ChatGPT and they told me it can't be done. But I wonder, for example, in the RSI the line changes as the price fluctuates at the moment the candle is formed, I want to do something similar.

Greetings.

```
if(strategy.opentrades > 0 and close >= pricelimitlong or strategy.opentrades > 0 and close <= pricestoplong)
    alert("Operacion Long Cerrada")
    strategy.exit("Buy Exit", from_entry="Buy", limit = pricelimitlong, stop = pricestoplong)

// IF SHORT
if(strategy.opentrades > 0 and close <= pricelimitshort or strategy.opentrades > 0 and close >= pricestopshort)
    alert("Operacion Short Cerrada")
    strategy.exit("Sell Exit", from_entry="Sell", limit = pricelimitshort, stop = pricestopshort)
```

I want the trade to close when the price reaches a specific point, not when the candle closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `strategy()` is not executed on every tick. So, even if you do;

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script", overlay=true)

plot(close)
```

This will not plot the current (`close`) price.

However, you can add `calc_on_every_tick=true` to your `strategy()` and make it update on every tick. This way, you can use `close` as current price. This will only work in real-time and not on the historical bars.